# Export a .NOFF file without color information

Tags: export

I have the following piece of code:

```
model = ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t] (3 + Cos[u]), Sin[t] (3 + Cos[u]), 
    Sin[u]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 2]
Export["out.noff", model, "NOFF", "BinaryFormat" -> False];
```

but the exported NOFF file is actually a CNOF file, containing color information for each vertex, which I don't want. How can I prevent this?

Thanks

Comment: The NOFF help page says it will output CNOF is color information present. What happens if you export something like `SphericalPlot3D[
  1 + Sin[4 \[Phi]]/2, {\[Theta], 0, Pi}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi}, 
  Lighting -> "Neutral", Mesh -> False, Axes -> False, 
  Boxed -> False] /. RGBColor[__] -> Sequence[]`?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I'm a bit late with thanking you, but it is much appreciated. Bedankt

Comment: I assume that it worked for you then, right?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries it did indeed.

Comment: OK, then to wrap this up, I made this an actual answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [NOFF help page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/NOFF.html) says it will output CNOF if color information present.

If you remove color information like in the example below it looks like you get a NOFF file without color information.

```
SphericalPlot3D[ 
  1 + Sin[4 ϕ]/2, 
  {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  Lighting -> "Neutral", Mesh -> False, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False
] /. RGBColor[__] -> Sequence[]
```